# An UCS2-UCS4 incompatibility import failure of a Cythnized pure-Python module

Tags: python, cython

I'm running into a cython-unicode problem which I hope you can help me with -

I'm trying to compile with cython a python module which works alot with unicode objects.

I'm working on Ubuntu 12.04 32bit, (on a VM on a **Win7 64bit** host if it has any importance), I'm using Py2.5.4 (can't change that) which I've installed side-by-side with the provided Py2.7.3 (and soft-linked `/usr/bin/python` to `/usr/bin/python2.5`), and Cython 19.02 (current one). I'm compiling with no special flags.

Now, as compiling goes seemingly OK, when I open a Py (same 2.5.4) and try to import the resulting. SO file, I get a PyUnicodeUCS2 type error. That is supposed to mean, as I understand, that the SO was compiled on a python configured with UCS4, and imported to python configured with UCS2. But It's the same python I compiled on and imported to.

for compilation I use `$ python setup.py bild_ext --inplace` where setup.py uses `distutlis.extension.Extension` and `Cython.Distutile.build_ext` .

Can someone enlighten me with what's going on and what I can do with it?

I'll be happy to provide more details if I wasn't clear enough.

Thanks a lot..

Comment: What value is returned from `import sys; sys.maxunicode`?

Comment: A value about 110K, which obviously means that the python works with unicode chars of 4 bytes. The thing I dont understand is that I, seemingly at least, made my compilation on the same installation. So, were did the UCS2 come from?