# Embedded Cython UCS2 UCS4 issue

Tags: python, c++, cython, ucs2, ucs-4

I have some python code I am trying to embed within c++ code using the cython api construct. For testing purposes I have been working off of:
[Example program of Cython as Python to C Converter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34480973/example-program-of-cython-as-python-to-c-converter)

With the slightly modified code:

```
#foo.pyx
cdef public foo(double* x):
    x[0] = 0.0

//file.cpp
#include "Python.h"
#include "foo.h"
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    double arr[2] = {1,2};
    foo(arr);
    std::cout << arr[0] << std::endl;
    std::cout << arr[1] << std::endl;
}
```

After running

```
cython foo.pyx
```

I attempt to compile receiving the error message:

```
foo.c:(.text+0x387): undefined reference to 'PyUnicodeUCS4_DecodeUTF8'
```

I have seen other questions regarding the matter, such as [An UCS2-UCS4 incompatibility import failure of a Cythnized pure-Python module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19888104/an-ucs2-ucs4-incompatibility-import-failure-of-a-cythnized-pure-python-module), and when I run:

```
import sys; sys.maxunicode
```

I get 1114111 which is in line with UCS4.  So what I am wondering is how to I resolve this undefined reference, when my python version seems to be line with the proper UCS there, but not elsewhere.

Comment: Did you remember to link against Python?

Comment: I include the python-config --cflags and python-config --ldflags in my CFLAGS and LDFLAGS respectively in my makefile.

Comment: I was not able to reproduce this problem. A [mcve] with complete details of gcc (g++) compile and link arguments should be included.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I had two different installations of python on my system and I was linking the wrong one.